# embed swf in fb and align it in center

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash

Hi I have created an swf file using AS3. I am able to embed it in html. When I open
that html from my system and I click on fullscreen than it is showing in center.

But when I post that page in Facebook and click on fullscreen than swf is not coming in center

check this link

https://www.facebook.com/pikSpeak/posts/547061845334010

you can click on the image and then click on fullscreen button (rightcorner) to see the problem.

can anyone suggest how to bring it in center ?

Comment: I see it exactly in center. You see it on right or on left?

Comment: I am seeing it on left

Comment: I have posted screen shot of it on https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwtaCeA2LQV4ZlZrT3BabHNkd28/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: very strange , i've cleaned the cache and it's still ok. i'm using chrome

Comment: I am also using chrome. I have tried with 11.6 and 11.7 flash version but its not working. Can you tell me which flash version you are having in chrome ?

Comment: 11.7.700.179 What screen resolution you have?

Comment: my screen resolution is 1366 x 768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the facebook embed object is changing the **stage.align** property.

Try to specify it in the Main class of the swf with **stage.align = ""**